# Could not able to generate the expected output

Tags: c++, permutation, backtracking, array-algorithms

https://leetcode.com/problems/permutations/
I'm unable to generate all the permutations for this problem. I followed the approach of generating all the subsets and then taking the subsets whose size is equal to our required size.
Below is the implementation of my code.

```
class Solution {
public:
    void check(vector<vector<int>> &res,vector<int> nums,vector<int> vect,int st)
    {
        
        if(st==nums.size())
        {
            if(nums.size()==vect.size())
            res.push_back(vect);
            return;
        }
        check(res,nums,vect,st+1);
        vect.push_back(nums[st]);
        check(res,nums,vect,st+1);
        vect.pop_back();
         
    }
    vector<vector<int>> permute(vector<int>& nums) {
        vector<vector<int>> res;
        vector<int> vect;
        check(res,nums,vect,0);
        return res;
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you have input that doesn't generate the right permutations?

Comment: Input: [1,2,3]
Expected Output: [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]
Actual Output: [[1,2,3]]